# InflateException when adding a third page to my FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I have an app with two pages in a support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter and things have worked fine for years. Now I wanted to add a third page, so I simply reused the same code from the old pages for the new one (changing id's and class names of course). And at first things seem to work, I can swipe from 1 - 2 - 3, but when I swipe back to page 2 again I get an InflateException for page number 1:

```
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080): Process: com.magnuswikhog.adrdangerousgoods, PID: 9080
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at com.magnuswikhog.adrlibrary.SearchPageFragment.onCreateView(SearchPageFragment.java:36)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1426)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:728)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:251)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #9: Duplicate id 0x7f0b00b2, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0b00b1 with another fragment for com.magnuswikhog.adrlibrary.SearchMasterFragment
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2289)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:169)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
01-12 14:55:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(9080):     ... 27 more
```

Here's my code:

From my FragmentPagerAdapter subclass:

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;           

        switch( position ){
            case 0:
                fragment = new SearchPageFragment();
                break;
            case 1:                 
                fragment = new LoadPageFragment();
                break;
            case 2:                 
                fragment = new InfoPageFragment();
                break;
        }

        return fragment;
    }
```

The code for page 1 (i.e. SearchPageFragment):

```
public class SearchPageFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_page_single_page, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/searchPageFragment" >


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/searchMasterFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.magnuswikhog.adrlibrary.SearchMasterFragment" />                  


</LinearLayout>
```

It seems the problem occurs in onCreateView() of page 1, when calling inflate() for the layout of page 1.

The id's being referred to in the error message are:

```
    public static int searchMasterFragment=0x7f0b00b2;
    public static int searchPageFragment=0x7f0b00b1;
```

Have tried a couple of "solutions" I managed to find when Googling, but so far the only thing that has worked has been to simply use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter - then the problem goes away. But I'm curious as to how I would resolve this issue and still use the FragmentPagerAdapter?

I guess the layout is being inflated again when swiping back, but none of the solutions (removing the view before inflating it again, removing the fragment in onDestroy(), storing the view in a member and checking if it's already != null, etc.) I have found so far have been able to help me prevent it.

BTW, I have checked that the support library classes rather than the standard ones are being used everywhere where they should.

Comment: One workaround (which doesn't really solve the underlying problem) seems to be to increase the number of pages the ViewPager keeps "alive" in the background. Using `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)` I am able to get it to work, but that's just covering up the symptoms...

Answer (score -1):

FragmentPagerAdapter is best for use when there are a handful of typically more static fragments to be paged through, such as a set of tabs. *The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible. This can result in using a significant amount of memory since fragment instances can hold on to an arbitrary amount of state.* For larger sets of pages, consider FragmentStatePagerAdapter. 
[for more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)

Comment: Thanks, but your Google documentation copy-n-paste answer does nothing to answer the question. I already stated that I have tried the FragmentStatePagerAdapter with success, but am curious as to why my code doesn't work with the FragmentPagerAdapter.